# Woocommerce - How to set variation as a product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a woocommerce web site and I have set a product with several variations. Each variation has a photo that shows in a gallery. When I change the variation the slide goes to variation image.

But what I need is when I select a color redirect me to product in that color.

I am using [LEBE *premium* theme](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/lebe-multipurpose-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/23157704?_ga=2.134658034.243806437.1614861209-581690123.1605529317)

I also try create simple products but in this case I don't have color.

[image]

There is any possibility to change this or am I stuck to the template's operation ?

Comment: Your issue is related to your swatches plugin (or to some javascript error generated by your theme or a plugin, that breaks WooCommerce gallery functionality)…

Comment: This is how Woocommerce works, selecting the colour swatch DOES change the product to that variation - it updates the price and stock info to that specific variation of the product. If you need more control than that you will have to do something custom - either create all products as simple products and group them some other way or get the page js to display whatever photos and info you need for each variation.